# php mysql "unique" error when table is created

Tags: mysql

So I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE activeSessions (
    id VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    claimtime int,
    mp FLOAT
);
```

When I put this into the database, this comes up:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    claimtime int,
    mp FLOAT
)' at line 2
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a length for the VARCHAR field?

Comment: VARCHAR requires a length. Probably in and float need digits and decimals

Comment: there's no php or mysqli here; please don't spam tag.

Comment: That is bad design. Why use VARCHAR on an id column to start with? You're better off using auto_increment.

Comment: btw, are you only responding to people who have posted in the answers area? You know that you can comment here, so don't be shy. Unless you feel that the comments posted don't mean anything to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VARCHAR requires a length when rendered on MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569963/varchar-requires-a-length-when-rendered-on-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the constraint after the column declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE activeSessions (
    id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    claimtime int,
    mp FLOAT,
    UNIQUE(id)
);
```

**Remember to give an INT value to the VARCHAR column.**

Comment: What's the error? Have you given a value to varchar?

Comment: You're missing a comma after `FLOAT`

Comment: Thank you @iainn!