# csvkit mysql import fails with VARCHAR requires a length on dialect mysql

Tags: mysql, csvkit

After installing csvkit with the following command

```
$ sudo -HE pip install --upgrade -e git+git://github.com/wireservice/csvkit.git@master#egg=csvkit
```

and trying to import a `.csv` as follows:

```
csvsql --db mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/jira_test --insert --table bugs_temp --no-constraints --overwrite --create-if-not-exists --no-inference --blanks bugs_temp.csv
```

I get the following error(s)

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_2".
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_3".
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_4".
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_5".
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_6".
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_7".
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_8".
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/agate/utils.py:292: DuplicateColumnWarning: Column name "0" already exists in Table. Column will be renamed to "0_9".
(in table 'bugs_temp', column 'ESS-3146'): VARCHAR requires a length on dialect mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(This answer might be somewhat uncomplete. I don't have experience with `csvsql`, so I'm making it a wiki.)</sup>

`csvkit` [depends](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/blob/d1cc54ffab1eb4f0a3a5afc8b7183db4ee1ec800/requirements-py3.txt#L6) on [`agate-sql`](https://agate-sql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which [depends](https://github.com/wireservice/agate-sql/blob/1ad8c6548ca9653a5f4bd796311ddbd6ce2e7fcb/requirements-py3.txt#L8) on [`sqlalchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

`sqlalchemy` contains [this line of code](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py#L1951):

```
    "VARCHAR requires a length on dialect %s" % self.dialect.name
```

It seems like ”*you need to specify lengths for all Strings*“, citing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569963/varchar-requires-a-length-when-rendered-on-mysql#5586870).

That means you cannot use the `--no-constraints` option:

```
  --no-constraints      Generate a schema without length limits or null
                        checks. Useful when sampling big tables.
```

See https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html